# Tag selector excluding potential matches as entered text gets *closer* to those matches

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-autocomplete

[image: suggestions for "badg"]

[image: suggestions for "badge"]

It seems like the suggestion algorithm is being a bit too picky or just doing something weird. I know there are lots of other tags with "badge" in their name, and apparently it does too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed in the next build. The fact that [badge](/questions/tagged/badge) is an exact match for the search term, and that it's a synonym of [badges](/questions/tagged/badges) (which itself contains the search term) confused the counting logic enough to only return five instead of six suggestions.